# SQL subquery as column with multiple where caluse

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have three tables `School, Grade, Student`. Table `Grade` has a `Foreign Key` column `s_id` that reference on `Primary Key` column `id` of `School` and table `Student` has a `Foreign Key` column `g_id` that reference on `Primary Key` column `id` of table `Grade`. I need to select school_name, number of student whose height is lower than 170 or higher than 180.For now, I write the select query like this.

```
SELECT School.name, School.id as sid, 
       (Select count(*) from Student inner join Grade on 
                     Student.g_id=Grade.id inner join School on 
                     Grade.s_id=School.id where School.id=sid and 
                     Student.height < 170) as under_170,  
       (Select count(*) from Student inner join Grade on 
                     Student.g_id=Grade.id inner join School on 
                     Grade.s_id=School.id where School.id=sid and Student.height > 180) as over_180
from School
```

I have to use `join` for each column.Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following uses the `SUM()` aggregator, and MySQL's treating a boolean as `1` or `0` when summing values to achieve your desired output.

```
SELECT school.id, school.name, SUM(student.height < 170) AS under_170, SUM(student.height > 180) AS over_180
FROM school
INNER JOIN grade ON (school.id = grade.s_id)
INNER JOIN student ON (grade.id = student.g_id)
GROUP BY school.id
```